# React Native can not preview image in android

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I use this library **[react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)** and **[react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer)**
The result I can preview images on IOS and android can not preview.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: ok let me add code

Comment: someone resolve how to do this? )